# UISearchBar width wrong in landscape

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, orientation, uisearchbar, landscape

My search bar is stretched slightly too far right when you start in landscape mode. It is still slightly too wide if you then rotate to portrait mode. However, its fine if you start in portrait mode and also if you then rotate it to landscape. Here is my code.

```
sBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[sBar sizeToFit];
sBar.delegate = self;
sBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
[self.view addSubview:sBar];
```

Comment: Can you do `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(sBar.frame));` after the `sizeToFit` call?

Comment: The width of the sBar is 20 bigger than thw width of the frame - sBar {{0, 0}, {320, 44}}
Frame {{0, 0}, {300, 480}}

Comment: Incidently, the width is 320, the same as the frame ... sBar {{0, 0}, {320, 44}}   Frame {{0, 0}, {320, 460}}

Comment: Mmm. Actually these figures dont add up, because surely in landscape it should be much wider than in portrait

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer was to add the search bar to the view before running the rest of the code.

```
UISearchBar * tempSBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.sBar = tempSBar;
[tempSBar release];

[self.view addSubview:sBar];
[sBar sizeToFit];
sBar.delegate = self;
sBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Comment: Incidentally, am i right to create the temp search bar, make that my search bar, then release the temp bar? (Bare in mind my search bar has been set to @property retain). Is this pointless or necessary? I'm fairly new to objective c and memory management.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin
```

add that to sBar.autoresizingMask, i have that aswell as the other 2 and have no issues. if you are using IB, make sure its the right width in there also

Comment: I tried that, but to my surprise it made no difference :S. Incidentally, I'm not using IB for this screen.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and deprecated, but I just had to share. I looked high and low for a solution that would work for my case. I tried all the suggestions, to no avail. Then I stumbled across this gem

```
// Update search bar frame.
CGRect superviewFrame = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.superview.frame;
superviewFrame.origin.y = 0.f;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.superview.frame = superviewFrame;
```

And everything became nice and sunny again. Thank you Peter at
http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/fixing-uisearchdisplaycontroller-on-ios-7/